# Swift 3: How to change button's image to UIImageView's image

Tags: uiimageview, uibutton, swift3

Is there any way I can change UIButton's image to UIImageView's image?

The UIImageView's image is from database.

Any help is appreciated, thank you so much!

Comment: Have you got any code?

Comment: Errr... okay, i know that if i change the button's image by using the image from assets library, the code would be: let redTapImage = UIImage(named: "redTap"), but instead of changing the button's image into the image from assets library, how can i change button's image by using UIImage's image or UIImageView's image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just set the button's image to `imageView.image`.

`button.setImage(imageView.image, for: .normal)`

Comment: Should be noted there is a distinction between `UIButton setImage:` and `UIButton setBackgroundImage`. Also you can adjust the properties of the UIButton's image view by using `[UIButton imageView].property` but I forget which one that correlates to backgroundImage or Image. Also my whole comment is in Objective-C, sorry.